# Making contextual filter conditions "OR" vs. "AND" in Drupal7

Tags: nodes, views

I have a view that needs to allow for the "OR" of a set of contextual filters (filtering on node references) rather than what appears to be the default of "AND". In the answer to a previous question here, someone suggested that there was a way to do this by changing the first filter group from OR to AND. My problem is that I am unable to find the menu to make this change.

Comment: Hello dwa, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. I am sorry, but I have to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: I need an answer to this question, but I cannot see which question it is meant to be a duplicate of. Where do I see that?