# OR condition in Views Contextual Filters

Tags: views

I have a Content Type named "Match" which has a local and visitor. Both are node references to a Content Type named "Team".

In Views I need to ask for matches of a specific team, no matter if that team is the local or the visitor. In contextual filters I can set a value for "local" and for the "visitor" each one in particular. So I guess I need an OR condition in this case.

Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

**Edit**: I found [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) module already but that's the problem, my website is too big and currently in production so we don't want to have problems because of bugs or something.

Comment: Re "we don't want to have problems because of bugs or something": You don't deploy directly on a production server, even for code you wrote.

Comment: Are you using GIT on your production website?

Comment: FYI, duplicate question and code based answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13531828/763010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Drupal 7:

If using D7, then consider module [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) (which only has a dev version today). Excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides a views plugin which modify query to support OR conditions for contextual filters.

A few issues on Drupal.org that may be of some help:

- [Using OR in filters breaks contextual filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/1367304).
- [Views AND/OR Contextual filters two ways](https://www.drupal.org/node/1451218).

There is also [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1111722#comment-9663681) in the support forum.

StackOverflow.com contains yet [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531828/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-or-logic) to consider as an alternative.

Maybe you should look at [Alter a Views query to use "OR" through the user interface](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3868) also (it might help to change change your mind about the [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) module anyway). Because 3,855 reports installs of that module is not nothing, right?

### Drupal 6:

If you're still using D6, then maybe module [Views OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_or) is what you are looking for? Excerpt from its project page:

> By default, each record in a view must match all filters. Sometimes records need to be included if they match one or more filters in a list of alternatives. Views has the ability to combine filters only with AND. If one filter is false, the combined list will be false. Views Or adds the ability to combine blocks of filters with OR. If one of the filters in the block is true, the combined block will be true.

### Note about the "my website is too big" ...

That's perfectly understandable. But that also implies that you should really invest in setting up some kind of testing / staging environment where you have like a mirror of your production environment. So that in THAT environment you can safely experiment / review / finetune what's needed, without impacting your production environment. And after you found the fix in that environment, you should have a process in place to actually MIGRATE it to the production environment ...

A pretty forward (simplistic) approach to this is to transform your existing production site into a multi site setup, whereas you do not change anything to the production site version, but you just add 1 (or more) sites like 'test', 'QA', 'User Acceptance Testing'. These extra sites mostly use the same code base (as production), but with their own copy of the Drupal database. And code changes (or extra modules to be added), first go in site specific subdirs. After they get approved, they are "promoted" to the "all" subdir.

Comment: Yeah i found "Views Contextual Filters OR" module but that's the problem, my website is too big and currently in production so we don't want to have problems because of bugs or something. BTW thank you

Comment: Thank you for the accept, a b it late, but still: merci beaucoup! Next question?

Comment: There is a Drupal 8 version of the `views_contextual_filters_or` module already.