# Views, taxonomy and content type

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a content page called **Book**, to which I also added an image field and a "term reference" to a **Book** taxonomy which has Book A, Book B, Book C, Book D, Book E as available terms in it.

I created 5 'Book' pages, inserted images and selected taxonomy terms (each taxonomy value are different).

I have another content page called **List Book**, to which I added a "term reference" to a **Book** taxonomy as well.

When I create a 'List book' page, I have to select a term from the **Book** taxonomy. If I select the terms 'Book A' and 'Book C', two images (related to Book A and Book C) will display.

Lastly I created a **view** with as a field the image field. As the filter, I added:

- 'publish = yes'.
- 'content type = Book' and 'List Book'.
- taxonomy field from 'List Book'.

Field: 
image from **Book**

There is no result.

What is the correct way?

Comment: I did a major edit of your extremely hard to understand question. I mostly only corrected grammar, and grouped together (moved around) the various phrases you had in the question. I'm unsure about the 3rd paragraph now, but I think it should be MERGED also into the 1st paragraph. Please review my edit, and re-edit/correct where needed. Lastly, about your question at the end: the correct way to do "WHAT"? Please edit your question to ALSO make that clear. Note about 2nd bullet near end: I doubt that "and" in it is correct (but I didn't want to change the meaning of your question). Your turn!

Comment: @Pierre, Thanks for your reply. I had edited my question.

Comment: I re-visited this question, but after your latest edit I keep wondering abot this: (a)  about 2nd bullet near end: I doubt that "and" in it is correct (shouldn't that be an "OR"?) and (b) about your question at the end: the correct way to do "WHAT"?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm getting here from your question is, you want to search on the basis of category. 
I think, you can use exposed filter in the views to get your desired result.

You can find exposed filer in views Under "Filter Criteria".

Hope it will help you.

Comment: As I mention: Lastly I created a view with as a field the image field. As the filter, I added:

'publish = yes'.
'content type = Book' and 'List Book'.
taxonomy field from 'List Book'.

Comment: Yes, Pierre is right. You can change 'And' with 'OR', this will show results for you.

Answer (score 0):

About the **There is no result** you added (in your latest edit): that is probably because of the "and" in the 2nd bullet of your views filter ... a content type can only have 1 value, but with the "and" you can never find any hit. So remove the "and", and see if you get a "better" result (at least not empty anymore.

**If** that views filter in the 2nd bullet is supposed to be an "OR" instead of "AND", **then** refer to my answer in [OR condition in Views Contextual Filters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158891/or-condition-in-views-contextual-filters/158892?s=2%7C0.9540#158892) ...