# How to use one of the 2 context filters in a view (with an OR)?

Tags: 8, views, entities, commerce

I have a view with 2 relations with the store for 2 different entities.

I want to filter the view with the store id for the 2 relationships.

I created 2 context filters in the views. You must use the first context filter OR the second.

How to do this ? If 2 filters are added, there are no results

[image]

Comment: You can use OR conditions with contextual filters using this contrib module.
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OR condition in Views Contextual Filters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158891/or-condition-in-views-contextual-filters)